# sql - getting the count of employee in each grade in a specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql ,I have a table like this

```
Emp_id    |  Emp_NAME | EMP_GRADE
  1           Test1      A1
  2           Test2      A2
  3           Test3      A3
  4           Test4      A4
  6           Test5      A1
  7           Test6      A2
  8           Test7      A3
```

I need to get the count of the employee in each grade , in which the final ouput will be 
 "2 - 2 - 2 - 1 " in a single column  where output refers (Count of Employee in each Grade ie A1(2) - A2(2)- A3(2) -A4(1)) . can anyone give sql query for this. I hope we dont need cursor for this .

Comment: Which is it, SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: coalesce will work for you. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
   DECLARE @Grades varchar(1000)

  SELECT @Grades=coalesce(@Grades + ' ','') +Cast(COUNT(EMP_GRADE) as Varchar(2))+' -'  From TableName 
  Group By EMP_GRADE

  Select @Grades=SUBSTRING(@Grades,0,LEN(@Grades))
  Select @Grades
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT @Grades=coalesce(@Grades + ' ','') +Cast(COUNT(t1.EMP_GRADE) as Varchar(2))+' -'  From @tab1 t
Left Join @tab1 t1 On t1.EMP_GRADE= t.EMP_GRADE And  t1.Emp_id= t.Emp_id 
And t1.EMP_GRADE<>'A3' -- Replace conditions here
Group By t1.EMP_GRADE,t.EMP_GRADE
```

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply . I want like "2 - 2 - 2 - 1" not with "T1(2) - T2(2) - T3(2) - T4(1) "

Comment: thanks a lot ken clark .. exactly working . have one issue with this .. if i filter with some condition say i have employee code which is unique that doesnt have any A3 grade . If i use this query it should return "2-2-0-1" inwhich "0" refers no grade for the current selection

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear. Can you please paste your exact condition.

Comment: consider i have one more columns named "EmployeeCode" which is unique and "EmployeeCode" does not have any employee with grade "A3" , then if i add  query

  SELECT @Grades=coalesce(@Grades + ' ','') +Cast(COUNT(EMP_GRADE) as Varchar(2))+' -'  
  From TableName  where EmployeeCode = 1
  Group By EMP_GRADE 

  Then it should return "2-2-0-1"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Emp_id) FROM myTableName GROUP BY EMP_GRADE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT ' - ' + CAST(COUNT(1) AS VARCHAR(max)) 
  FROM myTable 
  GROUP BY EMP_GRADE 
  ORDER BY EMP_GRADE 
  FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 3, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fd6d/4)

---

If you are filtering but still want to return results for every grade, you will need a self-join to get the full list of grades. Here's one way:

```
;WITH g AS (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_GRADE FROM myTable)
SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT ' - ' + CAST(COUNT(t.Emp_id) AS VARCHAR(max)) 
  FROM g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable t ON g.EMP_GRADE = t.EMP_GRADE
      AND t.Emp_id % 2 = 1 --put your filter conditions here as part of the join
  GROUP BY g.EMP_GRADE
  ORDER BY g.EMP_GRADE
  FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 3, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fd6d/7)

Comment: thanks exactly what i needed  . have one issue with this .. if i filter with some condition say i have employee code which is unique that doesnt have any A3 grade . If i use this query  it should return "2-2-0-1" inwhich "0" refers  no grade for the current selection

Comment: @premeclat Ok, I've added an example of how to do that. This assumes you don't have a separate `Grades` table. If you did, you could select from that instead of `g`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT EMP_GRADE, COUNT(EMP_Id) AS EMPS_COUNT
FROM TableName
GROUP BY EMP_GRADE
```

Hope that helps. Keep learning SQL.